# Angular protractor executeScript / executeAsyncScript: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, protractor

I'm trying to retrieve the isolated scope on a directive in protractor using the following code:

```
protractor.executeAsyncScript(function(callback){
    var isolatedScope = angular.element("div[my-directive='data']").isolateScope();
    callback(isolatedScope);
}).then(function(isolatedScope){
    console.log("directive's isolatedScope:", isolatedScope);
});
```

Unfortunatley I'm getting the following error from Chrome:

UnknownError: Unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.131)

Comment: you could have answered your own question since you got the answer on GitHub (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/767) This would have helped me as well !

Answer (score 4):

You should not send back objects which are too big/complex from the client to protractor. In your case, `isolatedScope` is too big.

This can happen with `executeAsyncScript()`, `executeScript()` and `evaluate()` (which use `executeScript()`).

If you are troubleshooting a problem, can you reproduce it outside of protractor ? Then it's very easy to observe the scope : right click "inspect element", then in dev console, type `$scope`

If you are trying to inspect the scope for tests reasons, then you are not testing at the right place. Protractor tests are high level "black box" tests. You anly care about user perspective, ex. "is the button visible ?". The user will never interact with the scope, nor should you. For testing a directive internal state, use DOM client unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error occurs is when a function calls itself. For example

```
let next = async function () {
    await $nextButton.click();
    await next();
}
```

What happens here is the code gets in an infinite loop and throws the error

Thus just go over your code and make sure you don't do it somewhere by accident